# Visual C#: Adjust Form Size

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been trying to use a button to extend the size of my form. However, for some reason, it won't let me do this. I'd think this would be an easy thing to accomplish, but I get the error:

"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Width.get'

The code I'm using that causes that error is

```
    private void options_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileSortForm.Height = 470;
    }
```

FileSortForm is the name of my Form. Also, from the advice of another site, I added this code into the Form Load code.

```
this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(693, 603);
```

Comment: Did you used to program in VB?  It's relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the height of a specific instance of your form.  Most likely in your case `this` will be the instance you want to modify:

```
private void options_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Height = 470;
}
```

Comment: Oh. That's different.
So how does the "this" work? I thought it just meant whatever object the code was for...

Comment: "this" is the current instance of the class cf.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `FileSortForm` is the name of your *class*, not your form instance. If this is the case, you can simply write

```
private void options_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Height = 470; // "this" is your form instance.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a static property that doesn't exist. You need to reference the non static method that does exist.

If the options_Click method is inside of your FileSortForm.

```
this.Height = 470;
```

If the options_Click method is outside of the FileSortForm you have to use the reference. Something like:

```
subForm.Height = 470
```

Edit:

Inside of the containing class the 'this' qualify is unnecessary (unless you are calling an overridden method).